# How to update constraints after adding UIView from xib on UIScrollView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewScroll`(background color is blue) in view controller. I need a `UIView`(background color is white) that were from Xib. The Xib view has a `UILabel`(background color is green) with constraints. Now, the problem is `UILabel` constraints not applied after adding it to `scrollView`. How to add `UIView` without loss of constraints? Refer following screenshots and code.

**Note:**

I need to just update constraints of the sub views of the `UIView` without using `IBOutlets` of `NSLayoutConstraints`.

**`UIView` on Xib:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var profileView:UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.profileView = UINib.init(nibName: "ProfileView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self)[0] as! UIView
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.profileView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.profileView.layer.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.profileView.frame.height)
        self.profileView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.frame.width/2, y: (self.profileView.frame.height/2)+10)
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Update:** More Information

I am aware to set `contentSize` of the scrollView. I used `layer` properties of `UIView` for manipulating height and width of the `UIView`. Instead of changing height and width also I need to update constraints of the sub views of `UIView`.

This is an example for understanding. But, In real I will be add more views like that.

**Github Repository :**
https://github.com/RAJAMOHAN-S/ScrollViewTest

**Required output:**

[image]

Comment: Why dont you add label inside profile view programmatically? or is it  against the requirement?

Comment: Try setting frame to profile view in viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S - why are you setting `.layer` properties? And, you need to provide more information... Do you want the XIB view to be sized to *fill* the scroll view? If so, what are you going to use to control the `.contentSize`? If you *don't* want it to completely fill the scroll view, how big do you want it, and where do you want it placed? And then again, what controls the `.contentSize`?

Comment: OK - do **not** manipulate the `.layer` properties. That's not what you want to do, and that won't give you the results you want. Instead, you need to set either the `.frame` or `.constraints` on the loaded view. Are you still unable to get what you want with WsCandy's answer?

Comment: In your GitHub repo, you do not have any constraints set on the Label in your XIB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152456/discussion-between-donmag-and-rajamohan-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to set the constraint of `self.profileView` programmatically, I've added an example below to get you started.

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    private var profileView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.profileView = UINib.init(nibName: "ProfileView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self)[0] as! UIView
        self.configureProfileView()
    }

    private func configureProfileView() -> Void {

        self.profileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.profileView)
        self.profileView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.profileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true

        // Pin the profile view to the top of the scrollView
        self.profileView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

More information can be found here too: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: I'll quickly see if I can replicate the issue and get back to you

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S - try it with that code... figure out what's wrong, and fix it. Here's a tip: you have to set the width and height constraints of your `.profileView`

Comment: @DonMag is correct. Leading and trailing anchors were not the right choice for this situation. I've edited my answer to include height and width constraints instead. I've tested this and confirmed it's working.